# i want to add "list_a" to "list_b"

Tags: python

```
temp_list = [2,2,9]
var_a = 2

list_a = []
print("first temp_list : ",temp_list)
print()

while temp_list[-1] >= var_a:
    before_end_value = temp_list[-1]
    temp_list[-1] = var_a
    temp_list.append(before_end_value - var_a)
    list_a.append(temp_list)
    print("temp_list", temp_list)
    print("list_a : ", list_a)
    print()
```

-----output-----

```
first temp_list :  [2, 2, 9]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 7]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 7]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```

i want to make list_a [[2,2,2,7],[2,2,2,2,5],[2,2,2,2,2,3],[2,2,2,2,2,2,1]]
(to solve this problem i used list_a.append(temp_list) but list_a have wrong values)

can you advise for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your latest edit, Here is the solution:

```py
temp_list = [2,2,9]
var_a = 2

list_a = []
print("first temp_list : ",temp_list)
print()

while temp_list[-1] >= var_a:
    before_end_value = temp_list[-1]
    temp_list[-1] = var_a
    temp_list.append(before_end_value - temp_list[-1])
    list_a.append(temp_list.copy())
    print("temp_list", temp_list)
    print("list_a : ", list_a)
    print()
```

just need to replace `list_a.append(temp_list)` with `list_a.append(temp_list.copy())`

Output:

```
first temp_list :  [2, 2, 9]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 7]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 7]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]]

temp_list [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
list_a :  [[2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 2, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: thank you so much. and sorry about bad english and bad question quality... i am learning python and english at the same time. thank you!

Comment: @mulkerdead wish you do it well. it would be great if you accept my answer by clicking on the Tik button.